# How to display uploaded file name in magento 2 admin form?

Tags: magento2

I have created file upload from in admin and it's successfully uploaded after browse the file. but it can not display selected file name after uploaded file. In firebug , i can see input tag in value attribute contain path of file but it can see "No file selected." . see the below screen shot.

[image]

File upload code is given below.

```
$path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('uploadfolder');

         $filepath = $path.'/'.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];


            if(file_exists($filepath) != 1)
            {
                $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'uploadfile']);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png','doc','pdf','xls','docx','zip','mp4','avi','mp3','txt','xlsx','vob']);  
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);  
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $uploader->save($path);
                return $path;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

Please help me where i am doing mistake ?

Thanks